# Can i assign variables as an array value?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

```
    <!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

<script>
    var foodItem0 = prompt("Enter your favorite food");
    var foodItem1 = prompt("Enter your second favorite food");
    var foodItem2 = prompt("Enter your third favorite food");
    var allFood = [foodItem0,foodItem1,foodItem2];

    function favoritefood(){
        for(x=0;x>allFood.length;x++){
        var id="item"+x;
        var li=document.getElementById(id);
        li.innerHTML=allFood[x];
        }
    }
window.onload=favoritefood; 


</script>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Top Three Favorite Food Items</h1>
    <ol>
    <li id="item0"></li>
    <li id="item1"></li>
    <li id="item3"></li>
    </ol>

</body>
</html>
```

If i am allowed to declare the array "allfood" like that please explain why the code is not working the list numbers are showing up but not the food that i enter in the prompts

Comment: Look in your browser console for errors. `document.getElementById("item2")` returns `null`. Your ids should be `item0`, `item1`, `item2`.

Comment: Also `for(x=0;x < allFood.length;x++){`. `<` not `>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var allFood = [foodItem0,foodItem1,foodItem2];
```

this is perfectly valid. This means that you are creating an array.

1. The code doesn't work, because of the condition in the for loop.

   ```
   for(x=0;x>allFood.length;x++){
   ```

   It should have been

   ```
   for(x=0; x < allFood.length;x++){
   ```
2. After fixing that, you need to change the `id` of the last list item, which says `item3`, you might want to change it to `item2`.

Answer (score 0):

Your "less than" symbol in your  for loop is backwards. As such, your loop is exiting without running the code inside.

Comment: thefoutheye got to it before me. He is correct. Upvoting his answer.